# Angular - Quiero que mi servicio retorne un usuario

Tags: angular, api, servicio

tengo un servicio **ejemploServicio** con el metodo `home()` que, pasandole un **token**, me debe devolver el usuario correspondiente:

```
  public  home(){
    let token = this.authService.getToken();
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`
    });
    return this.http.get(this.REST_API_SERVER+this.HOME,{headers:headers});
  }
```

Luego lo uso en mi componente de esta forma :

```
let user = ejemploServicio.home()
```

Lo que pasa es que eso lo tengo que tratar con un observable, y tendria que hacer un subscribe tal y cual. ¿No hay alguna forma de que retorne el user o null? El `async` y el `await` deberia solucionarmelo pero no he dado con la tecla en los intentos que he hecho. Quiero que el servicio sea como una funcion corriente que retorne algo y le pueda asignar eso a una variable.

Answer (score 1):

Tal y como tienes el código, hasta que no te suscribas a él no va a llamar al API. Podrías subscribirte tal y como dices de la siguiente forma:

```
ejemploServicio.home().subscribe(user => {
  // Codigo para gestionar el usuario devuelto
});
```

Si en su lugar quieres utilizar `async/await` puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
let user = await ejemploServicio.home().toPromise();
```

Recuerda que de esta forma tendrías que poner `async` al principio del método dentro del cual usas este código.

Comment: Buenas, lo primero gracias por contestar. Mira al final lo he dejado con el subscribe, pero la verdad no me gusta, ya que es un servicio http muy simple : o retorna el usuario o es nulo. Me gustaria que toda la logica fuera en el servicio y hacerlo con el await, pero tal como tienes en el segundo ejemplo no me ha funcionado ( he puesto el async en la funcion)